# IObservable.Subscribe OnNext action is not blocking in blazor webassembly

Tags: c#, system.reactive, blazor-webassembly, rx.net

I am using https://github.com/dotnet/reactive
I use CombineLatest to combine observableA (emits items by timer) with observableB (insert manually).
In OnNext method sometimes i insert new value to observableB
In that case new iteration of OnNext starts immediately before current OnNext returns.

```
 _subscription = _observable.ClientData
        .CombineLatest(_deviceTypeFilterViewModel.Filters)
        .Subscribe(OnNext, OnError);

private void OnNext((IClientDataSlice slice, Filtter filter) sliceWithFilter)
{
   Logger.Log(Slice.Number + " start");
   //... pseudo code:
   _deviceTypeFilterViewModel.Filters.Add(someValue)
   Logger.Log(Slice.Number + " end");
}
```

Will be executed like:

```
1 start
2 start
....
```

Instead of

```
1 start 
1 finish
2 start
2 finish
```

When i did the same in blazor server hosted it worked as expected: new OnNext not started untill previous method returns. Is that by design?

Comment: This library looks pretty niche.  Ask the person that made the library by posting an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Publishing a value is just like invoking an event delegate. Calling `OnNext` on your subject (or however you're publishing to ObservableB) is going to synchronously call `OnNext` in your observer, which means that method will run to completion before your code continues. This can be changed by adding `.ObserveOn(ThreadPoolScheduler.Default)` to your rx chain. Doing so would cause publishing a value to trigger threadpool work, which will wait for a threadpool thread to become available and run it there. This still won't make your first subscription complete before the second one runs - for that, you may need to look into a primitive locking mechanism or consider calling `.Synchronize()` in your rx chain (depending on the code you have running). Note that these options could cause a deadlock if you don't properly dispatch your work to the threadpool.